# @Enumerated ( EnumType.ORDINAL, EnumType.STRING )

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, enums

I wanted to add enumerated values into my web application ( spring, java ) and i have found this article http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/hibernate/hibernate-enum-type-mapping-example.
I followed steps and it works thank God but here is the question. I added `@Enumerated(EnumType.String)` on getter in my entity ( the article from link above says if i put .STRING it will save string value instead of 1,2,3,4. So i run the app save the entity and no matter what `enumtype` i put ( string or ordinal ) i always get 0,1,2 in my database, so i tried to make that column varchar, and still with .String i get 0,1,2. I manage to print out gender values out without any problem with

```
                    <form:select path="gender">
                    <form:option value="MALE">MALE</form:option>
                    <form:option value="FEMALE">FEMALE</form:option>
                    </form:select>
```

and i get **MALE or FEMALE due 0 and 1** in database, but I still wonder why it won't save string when i put proper annotation on getter ?

Comment: did you convert your old values in the DB from ordinal to string?
moreover, indeed you have to use a varchar2 (big enough to contain the biggest string value of your Enum)...
btw, i think that mysql has the `enum´ type and it can be used for your enum ;-)